# Touching an area of screen dismisses view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I've never seen a problem like this until now. When I first updated my app, this problem did not exist. It was fine. Since then there've been a couple of iOS updates, so it's possible this is where the problem began.

I basically have a few view controllers that proceed like a wizard from one step to the next, by either clicking back/cancel button or the next button.

There's a textView covering the main area.

Normally by touching inside the textView it would begin editing.

On this viewcontroller it's fine, that works. No problem.

[image]

On this viewcontroller and every subsequent view controller including tableviews with options to select, if you touch anywhere underneath the cancel and next buttons inside the view controller, it dismisses the view controller and goes back to the previous screen. There doesn't appear to be anything executed in my code when this happens. It just dismisses the view controller as if one pressed the back button. I know the back button code is not being executed because I printed a line in there.

[image]

The next view controller is a tableView and does not have a textView. It's got nothing to do with the textView. It just dismisses if I touch anywhere on the screen other than the next or cancel buttons. The next views are the exact same way. It's like a big invisible button is in the way of the screen blocking any interaction with the top half.

What's going on here? How do I fix this? It has never done this before and I didn't change anything.

Comment: Did you do something with keyboard dismiss(in any view controller)?

Comment: Turns out that this was caused by using page curl transitions. I should never have used those transitions. I changed it to flip horizontal and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that this was caused by using page curl transitions. I changed it to flip horizontal and it works now.  Page curl transitions are obviously bugged currently.

Comment: I don't think that is enough evidence to conclude that simply the page curl transition is "bugged" - can you reproduce the problem? If you think it actually is bugged make sure to submit a report to apple - did you also try debugging as opposed to just using prints as you mentioned?

Comment: There was nothing to debug in my code. Simply changing it back and forth from Page Curl transitions to Horizontal Flip transitions fixed the problem and reproduced it. The bug did not exist in my app when I first submitted it, it began after an iOS update and someone had to point it out to me.